# Eonasdan datetimepicker disable time, only date enabled

Tags: datepicker, angular, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using eonasdan-datetimepicker in my app with Angular 2. In some cases (based on selected service) I need datetimepicker, but in other cases, I need only datepicker (without time).

Is it possible to use only datetimepicker from eonasdan with some options to disable time or is necessary to import other datepicker only with date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format specified in the options defines what components are shown. 
Supported formats http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

There are further options to disable hours, ... https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/docs/Options.md

Comment: Thanks, it works! $("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker({}).data("DateTimePicker").format("MM/dd/YYYY");